# How to only let correct_user create or destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

How can we get it where only the `correct_user` can create or destroy here?

```
class DaysMissedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
    habit.save!
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days + 1
    if level.missed_days == 3
      level.missed_days = 0
      level.days_lost += habit.calculate_days_lost + 1
    end
    level.save!
    head :ok
  end

  def destroy
    habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days - 1
    habit.save
    level = habit.levels.find(params[:level_id])
    level.missed_days = level.missed_days - 1
    level.save!
    head :ok
  end

private

  def correct_user
    @habit = current_user.habits.missed_days.find_by(id: params[:id]) #I've tried different versions of this line
    redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
  end
end
```

Depending on what I put in the line where I commented I either get `"Not authorized to edit this habit"` or upon refreshing the page the checkmark I had made disappears even if I am the `correct_user`

**habit.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".habit-check").change(function()
  {
    habit = $(this).parent().siblings(".habit-id").first().attr("id");
    level = $(this).siblings(".level-id").first().attr("id");
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed",
         method: "POST"
       });
    }
    else
    {
       $.ajax(
       {
         url: "/habits/" + habit + "/levels/" + level + "/days_missed/1",
         method: "DELETE"
       });
    }
  });
});
```

In habit **show page** this is what I don't want other users to be able to edit via `:create` & `:destroy`:

```
 <% if @habit.current_level_strike %> 
    <div class="btn" id="red"> <label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id">Strikes:</label>
  <% else %> 
    <div class="btn" id="gold"> <label id="<%= @habit.id %>" class="habit-id-two">Strikes:</label>
  <% end %>
    <% @habit.levels.each_with_index do |level, index| %>
      <% if @habit.current_level >= (index + 1) %>
        <p>
          <% if @habit.current_level_strike %> 
            <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id">Level <%= index + 1 %>:</label> 
          <% else %> 
            <label id="<%= level.id %>" class="level-id-two">Level <%= index + 1 %>:</label> 
          <% end %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 0, {class: "habit-check"} %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 1, {class: "habit-check"} %>
          <%= check_box_tag nil, true, level.missed_days > 2, {class: "habit-check"} %>
       </p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**rails console**

```
[2] pry(main)> Habit.find(1)
  Habit Load (17.7ms)  SELECT  "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Habit:0x007f96c7133728
 id: 1,
 conceal: false,
 missed_days: 0,
 likes: 1,
 committed: ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", ""],
 date_started: Sun, 07 Jun 2015 00:00:00 UTC +00:00,
 trigger: "",
 action: "test",
 target: "",
 reward: "",
 private_submit: nil,
 user_id: 1,
 created_at: Sun, 07 Jun 2015 21:57:04 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 00:45:05 UTC +00:00,
 order: nil>
[3] pry(main)> Level.find(1)
  Level Load (14.0ms)  SELECT  "levels".* FROM "levels" WHERE "levels"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Level:0x007f96c7838c80
 id: 1,
 habit_id: 1,
 missed_days: 0,
 current_level: nil,
 created_at: Sun, 07 Jun 2015 21:57:04 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 00:45:05 UTC +00:00,
 days_lost: 0>
[4] pry(main)>
```

**habits_controller**

```
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @habits = Habit.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @habits = current_user.habits.order("date_started DESC")
    end
  end

  def show
    @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    @notable = @habit
    @notes = @notable.notes
    @note = Note.new
    @commentable = @habit
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
    @correct_user = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @habit = current_user.habits.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
    if (params[:commit] == 'conceal')
      @habit.conceal = true
      @habit.save_with_current_level
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created'
    elsif
      @habit.save_with_current_level
      track_activity @habit
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created'
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Required Fields: "Committed to", "Started", and "Enter Habit"'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @habit.update(habit_params)
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @habit.destroy
    redirect_to habits_url
  end

  def like
    @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    @habit_like = current_user.habit_likes.build(habit: @habit)
    if @habit_like.save
      @habit.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
    end  
      redirect_to(:back)
  end

  private
    def set_habit
      @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @habit = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
    end

  def habit_params
    params.require(:habit).permit(
      :user_id, 
      :trigger,
      :tag_list,
      :current_level,
      :missed_days,
      :target, 
      :reward,
      :comment,
      :commentable,
      :like,
      :likeable,
      :private,
      :action,
      :order,
      :date_started,
      :missed_one,
      :notes_text,
      :notes_date, 
      :notable, 
      :note, 
      :committed => [],
      levels_attributes: [
      :missed_days,
      :days_lost], notes_attributes: [:notable, :note, :notes_text, :notes_date, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

Here's the **[gist of it](https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2)** (not fully updated but you get the idea)

Please let me know if you need further explanation or code to help you help me :)

### UPDATE ERROR

```
Started POST "/habits/1/levels/2/days_missed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-10 13:07:11 -0400
Processing by DaysMissedController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"habit_id"=>"1", "level_id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Habit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('ingrain'))
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Level Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "levels".* FROM "levels" WHERE "levels"."habit_id" = ?  [["habit_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "habits" WHERE "habits"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 21ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Habit without an ID):
  app/controllers/days_missed_controller.rb:32:in `correct_user'
```

Comment: What is the issue? In your before_action, you need to return `false` to prevent the action being called.

Comment: Is there a way I can check that? I am trying to figure out a way to rewrite the `correct_user` @AbM so that only the user who created the habit can create or destroy in the DaysMissedController.

Comment: Can you explain what "missed_days" is in relation to habit? Is it a field? A related model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe you've correctly identified that the problem lies within your correct_user method:

```
def correct_user
  @habit = current_user.habits.missed_days.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
end
```

Take a look at your first line, here's what I read in English:

- Take the current User
- Get that User's Habits
- Get those Habits' MissedDays
- Find me one of those missed days that matches params[:id]

Which, based on your data model, is sort of non-sensical. Missed Days is an **attribute** of a model, not a model itself. I'm not sure you can even call .find_by on a number, which makes it unsurprising that you keep getting nil.

I bet this'll work instead:

```
@habit = current_user.habits.find(params[:habit_id])
```

*Note that the find method always queries by the id attribute. Saved you a few characters. :)*

One other thing, in both create and destroy, you re-find the habit that you already found in the before_action. Try this:

```
def create
  @habit.missed_days = habit.missed_days + 1
  @habit.save
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks Lanny putting it in english makes more sense to me :) I got an error tho with your code hopefully we can figure it out. I added it to the question.

Comment: By reading the error, it appears that the params hash is more specific than either you or I were being... it's sending params[:habit_id]. Edited above.

Comment: You bet! Happy Rails-ing! :)